# Text wrapping in different major modes

Tags: org-mode, wrapping, visual-line-mode, truncate-lines

I visit a new file, Fundamental mode is automatically selected and newly inserted long lines are wrapped automatically.

I create an .org file, Org mode is automatically selected, I manually select Fundamental mode and yet newly inserted long lines are not wrapped!

Why?! Isn't text wrapping a feature of Fundamental mode regardless of the extension of the file I'm working on? Perhaps a minor mode is involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line wrapping behavior is influenced by two things:

- `visual-line-mode`, a minor mode
- `truncate-lines`, a variable. When the variable is set to `t` in a buffer, lines are truncated; when `nil`, they wrap at the window boundary. The variable  becomes permanently buffer-local when set - see its doc string with `C-h v truncate-lines`.

These settings are independent of major mode, although `org-mode` sets the `truncate-lines` variable to `t` if `org-startup-truncated` is `t` (the default value). Fundamental mode kills all local variables, with the exception of permanent ones - see the doc string of `kill-all-local-variables` which says:

> As a special exception, local variables whose names have a non-nil
> ‘permanent-local’ property are not eliminated by this function.  If
> the optional KILL-PERMANENT argument is non-nil, clear out these local
> variables, too.

Since `truncate-lines` was set locally but permanently in the Org mode buffer, it does not get killed when you switch to `fundamental-mode`. If you want to, you can call `kill-all-local-variables` with a `t` argument: `M-: (kill-all-local-variables t)`. That will get rid of the local variable, so that the global default (`nil`) will be in force. N.B. the (optional) argument to `kill-all-local-variables` was added to Emacs 29 - it is not available in Emacs 28.2 or earlier. You can check the doc string of the function with `C-h f kill-all-local-variables` to see if it mentions the variable KILL-PERMANENT.

Alternatively, you can use the `Options` menu item: click `Options/Line Wrapping this buffer` and choose whatever option you want from there. N.B. If you reset the value of `truncate-lines` this way, it will still be permanent local however.

Comment: Dear Nick, thanks for your very detailed answer! I tried:
M-: (kill-all-local-variables t)
and I get the error:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments kill-all-local-variables 1). Any idea why?

Comment: Ah, sorry - I should have checked: the optional argument to `kill-all-local-variables` was added on Oct 6 2021 in commit c0f7396588080ac48b72b905880d3f488e5becb3, so it might not be available yet in your version of Emacs. I'll do some more digging and update the answer with version information. What version of Emacs are you running?

Comment: Nick, I'm 28.2 which is the latest available via dnf. Don't bother: I will install 29.1 via Guix and should have no issue. I will report back if I need further clarifications! Thank you so much!

Comment: Updated the answer with version info and how to check by checking the doc string of the function.